# How can I print a Human readable ResourceList

Tags: kubernetes, client-go

How do I print a human readable [ResourceList](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/api/core/v1@v0.28.3#ResourceList)

Below is my function but I'd like `ResourceMemory` to scale based on the number of bytes.

For example, instead of 1024Mi instead print 1Gi etc..

Maybe there an existing function in the API I can use for this??

```golang
func printResourceList(resourceList v1.ResourceList) {
    for key, value := range resourceList {
        switch key {
        case v1.ResourceCPU:
            fmt.Printf("key: %-6s value: %s \n", key.String(), value.String())
        case v1.ResourceMemory:
            fmt.Printf("key: %-6s value: %vMi \n", key.String(), value.Value()/(1024*1024))
        default:
            fmt.Printf("key: %-6s value: %s \n", key.String(), value.String())
        }
    }
}
```